# $iV$ is open for $V$ open in real TVS

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex vector space. It induces a real vector space $E_0$. Suppose that on $E_0$ we have a topology compatible with the vector structure, ie. a **real** TVS. How do we prove that $E$ is a complex TVS with same topology?

What I know is this: We have maps
$$
\mathbb C \times E \to \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times E \to E \times E \to E \\
(x + iy, e) \mapsto (x, y, e) \mapsto (xe, ye) \mapsto xe + iye
$$

What's needed is $V$ open $\Rightarrow$ $iV$ open (ie. scalar multiplication by $i$ is continuous; note the inverse is $-i$).

Alternatively, if the claim were to be false, a counter-example would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does this all work out when $E$ is just $\mathbb{C}$ and $E_0$ is $\mathbb{R}$? There are some things you've said that don't seem consistent with that case (namely, that $E$ and $E_0$ could possibly have the same topology).

Comment: @Ian $E_0 = \mathbb C$ with real scalar multiplication. In fact, $E_0 = E$ as sets.

Comment: The scalar product is irrelevant to this discussion, but now I see your point, your $E_0$ is not a projection onto the "real part", it's just decomposing your complex space into two isomorphic real spaces.

Comment: @Ian I meant scalar multiplication. But I don't see how such a decomposition could be accomplished in a canonical fashion?

Comment: Anyway, can you prove that $E_0$ is the direct sum of two isomorphic spaces? Can you prove that these two spaces are also homeomorphic?

Comment: How do you mean "canonical fashion"? Do you mean without choosing a basis? I don't know about that, but when choosing a basis it is simple: given a basis $B$ for $E$ over $\mathbb{C}$, you have a basis for $E_0$ over $\mathbb{R}$ which is just $B \cup \{ iv : v \in B \}$.

Comment: @Ian I'm still too stupid to prove it, though the two spaces are obviously isomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is false : multiplication by $i$ may not be continuous.

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two real topological vector spaces, with same underlying set but two different topologies. Let $E = E_1 \times E_2$ with the natural struture of real topological vector space and with complex structure :
$$i : E_1 \times E_2 \longrightarrow E_1 \times E_2, \quad (x_1,x_2) \longmapsto (-x_2,x_1).$$
Then $E$ is not a topological complex vector space.

Comment: The simplest case may perhaps be $E_1 = E_2 = \mathbb R$ with two different topologies (e.g. standard and trivial), since then we see that the complex structure makes it into a vector space from the algebraic structure of the complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $(\lambda_j)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb C$ and $\{e_k\}$ a net in $E$ such that $\lambda_j\to\lambda$ and $e_j\to e$. We want to show that $\lambda_je_k\to\lambda e$.

If $\lambda_j=a_j+ib_j$ with $a_j,b_j\in\mathbb R$ we have $a_j\to a$ and $b_j\to b$. Using that $E$ is a complex vector space, 
$$
\lambda_je_k=a_je_k+ib_je_k\to  ae+ibe=(a+ib)e=\lambda e,
$$
using that $E_0$ is a (real) TVS.

Comment: While I see that $b_j e_k \to be$, I don't think that $i b_j e_k \to ibe$ has been proven.

Comment: Yes, you are right.